# Trying to dynamically generate chart inside a Bootstrap modal, getting offsetWidth Error

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I am using [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) which is HTML5 based library, to dynamically draw a chart inside a Bootstrap modal body. Everything is fine and I can see the correct data and label array has been passed, and canvas HTML node has been created, but I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
```

I thought maybe I am calling this function too early:

```
new Chart(--> HTML node <--).get(0).getContext("2d").Bar(--> data <--);
```

so I put it in [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) block to call the function after like 2 seconds of appending canvas HTML node, but I am still getting that error and not able to see the chart.

Here is the complete code ([github](https://github.com/amir734jj/SampleResultPage/blob/master/ResultPage.html), [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fycwfgb6m2nk679/AABKIx3EDRHBo3G2Dr0OxOvSa?dl=0)) and here is the part I am calling the chart libraray:

```
document.getElementById("modalBody").appendChild(canvasElement);

setTimeout(function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).get(0).getContext("2d").Bar(finalData);
    return finalData;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CVKXC6gfU88QU0B5A9pH?p=preview).

The basics of what I changed for both `contextualizeForType2()` and `contextualizeForType3()` are as follows:

1. The correct way to instantiate the bar chart component is using the 2D context for the canvas element you appended. In code, you have `new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d')).Bar(finalData);` after the `var ctx = ...` line. However, because the modal hasn't been shown yet, it will have a height and width of 0.
2. To have the chart use the correct height and width, you should bind to the `shown.bs.modal` event that gets triggered once the modal has finished animating in. Inside that event handler is where you create the chart. The tricky part comes because you have two different questions reusing the same modal. So I added an extra namespace of `.typeX`, which I unregister my events for when the modal gets hidden.

I know that second point is confusing, but hopefully the code clears it up:

```
var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
$('#myModal').on({
  'shown.bs.modal.type2': function() {
    new Chart(ctx.getContext("2d")).Bar(finalData);
  },
  'hidden.bs.modal.type2': function() {
    this.off('.type2');
  }
});
```

This means that once the modal gets hidden, these two functions won't get run again when the same modal is shown for the other type. Additionally, you won't be creating more charts than you need, due to adding a new handler every time the button is clicked.

#### Alternative method

I had [a further play](http://plnkr.co/edit/hKQi526KJVbeLQtKLS2y?p=preview) and found that I could refactor the code into a single function that can be called from both `contextualizeForType2()` and `contextualizeForType3()`, passing in the `finalData`. This has the advantage of leaving all the canvas and chart initialisation code in one place, simplifying your large functions somewhat and making it easier to maintain.

The function is:

```
function showModalChart(data) {
  var canvasElement = document.createElement("CANVAS");
  canvasElement.setAttribute("width", "400");
  canvasElement.setAttribute("height", "400");

  document.getElementById("modalBody").appendChild(canvasElement);

  var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  $('#myModal').off('.modalchart').on('shown.bs.modal.modalchart', function () {
      new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d')).Bar(data);
  });
}
```